# How to enable/disable links on jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying since a while with this code but I have trouble in dealing with it.

- "Click" should be disable when 0 or all of checkboxes are checked.
- "Action" should be disable no element is checked.

This is my code, it works on code snippet, but it doesn't on my navigator, I don't know exactly where is the problem, if in the event because I have an other event onclick inside this div or something else.

Thank you in advance.

```js
function activerSupressionMultiple(){
 var aptitudesASupprimer = jQuery('#suppressionMultiAptitudes input:checked');
 var nbrAptitudesPresentes = jQuery('#suppressionMultiAptitudes input:checkbox').length;
    var nbrItem = aptitudesASupprimer.length;
 if( nbrItem == nbrAptitudesPresentes)
  jQuery('#link1').removeAttr('href');
    else if (nbrItem == 0) 
        jQuery('#link2').removeAttr('href');
    else {
        jQuery('#link1').attr('href', '#');
        jQuery('#link2').attr('href', '#'); 
    };
};

function selectionnerToutesLesAptitudes() {
 jQuery('#suppressionMultiAptitudes input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true );
 activerSupressionMultiple();
};
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}

a {
  margin: 30px;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="suppressionMultiAptitudes" onchange="activerSupressionMultiple()">
<label><input type="checkbox"> option 1</label>
<label><input type="checkbox"> option 2</label>
<label><input type="checkbox"> option 3</label>
<label><input type="checkbox"> option 4</label>
<label><input type="checkbox"> option 5</label>
</div>

<a id="link1" href="#" onclick="selectionnerToutesLesAptitudes(); return false;">Select All</a>
<a id="link2" onclick="action(); return false;">Action</a>
```

Comment: *This is my code, it works on code snippet, but it doesn't on my navigator* are you missing jQuery reference?

Comment: Action btn does not work in snippet, in clicks even when disabled

Comment: @ShaunakD Yeap I included a jQuery reference because I have other functions use jQuery.

Comment: @johnpan I didn't write the code of the event action, it could be an alert for example.

Comment: Why does your `div` have an `onchange` event?

Comment: @Chinovski yes, I saw. But it calls the action() method even when disabled

Comment: @ShaunakD to detect changes on checkboxes, there is an other way to do it?

Comment: Yes. See for jquery change event. `$('input:checkbox').change(function(){..})`

Comment: @johnpan Oh, you are right, I didn't pay attention :/

Comment: @ShaunakD, Thank you, but how to call this function inside the 2nd one?

Comment: You have to init this in dom ready handler.

Comment: The problem is that I have other functions in the js file, I already used a function likke this and it works

`function activerBoutonMultiAptitudes (){
 var nbrChecked = function() {
  var n = jQuery( ".aptitudesDeLaCategorie :checked" ).length;
  if (n == 0) jQuery('#lienAjouterAptitudes').removeAttr('href');
  else jQuery('#lienAjouterAptitudes').attr("href", "#");
 };
 nbrChecked(); 
 jQuery( ".aptitudesDeLaCategorie input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click", nbrChecked );
};`

Answer (score 0):

Remove "onchange" on your div.

```
<div id="suppressionMultiAptitudes">
<label><input type="checkbox"> option 1</label>
<label><input type="checkbox"> option 2</label>
<label><input type="checkbox"> option 3</label>
<label><input type="checkbox"> option 4</label>
<label><input type="checkbox"> option 5</label>
</div>

<a id="link1" href="#" onclick="selectionnerToutesLesAptitudes(); return false;">Select All</a>
<a id="link2" onclick="action(); return false;">Action</a>
```

Add event for call your function :

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function(){
   activerSupressionMultiple();
})
```

Result : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7b6rkvbj/5/)

Comment: Thank you for your help, but using this method I cannot use the other function that calls activerSupressionMultiple()

Comment: It doesn't work :/ but I prefer not to use document..ready because I have other forms on html file and other functions in the js file